# SQL Query Predicament

Tags: sql

I need to create an sql query which retrieves the sum of commission and salary from an agent that is less than the salary of the lowest earning manager

Here is my query so far I am receiving a blank table:

```
SELECT AgentName, 
       Salary,
       Commission,
       (SELECT sum(Premium) 
        From Policy,PolicyCover 
        WHERE AgentNo IN ( Select AgentNo From Policy)) As [Total Premium]
FROM Agent,Policy,PolicyCover
WHERE (Select sum(Salary+Commission) 
       From Agent) <
      (Select Min(Salary) 
       From 
       Agent Where Function= "Manager")
```

Comment: Please post the structure of these db tables

Comment: For a start don't use comma-separated joins. You seem to be a beginner, so who taught you to use a join syntax that was made redundant in **1992**? Then you are selecting from the same tables again and again. Your subqueries are not even related to the main query.

Comment: You have been asked to show the table structures. Please do this. What column belongs to what table? What are the tables' primary keys? (By the way: Please add the MS Access tag. I cannot as there is an edit pending. Never ask SQL questions without tagging your DBMS.)

Answer (score 1):

You are a beginner, so I think it would not help that much if I showed you a prêt-à-porter query. Instead I'll tell you what your query does.

You are using an out-dated join syntax. You can replace the comma between the table name by the explicit keywords `CROSS JOIN`. So your main query has:

```
FROM Agent, Policy, PolicyCover
```

which translates to

```
FROM Agent CROSS JOIN Policy CROSS JOIN PolicyCover
```

and means: Take every record from Agent and combine them with every record from Policy and then take the resulting rows and combine them with every record in PolicyCover. Lets say Agent has 100 records, Policy 200 and PolicyCover 300. That makes 100 x 200 x 300 combination = 6,000,000 rows.

Now to the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (Select sum(Salary+Commission) From Agent) <
      (Select Min(Salary) From Agent Where Function = "Manager")
```

So you select the sum of salary plus commison from Agent. Then you select a minimum salary from Agent, which is of course less then the sum of all salaries (plus commissions). So the condition is never met. You select no records.

If you had a `WHERE` clause where the condition were met, you'd select some columns from the myriads of combined rows plus a sum of premium values. Let's look at that subquery: You cross join Policy and PolicyCover , thus creating all combinations. In `WHERE` you make sure that the AgentNo you got from the Policy table exists in the Policy table. Well, this is always true of course.

First thing: Learn proper joins (`INNER JOIN ... ON ...` to start with). Think about what relates the tables and only join related records (e.g. with the same policy number).

Next thing: make it a habit to qualify your columns when working with more than one table. Is Premium for instance a column of Policy or PolicyCover? Make this obvious by specifying the table name: `SUM(PolicyCover.Premium)`. Or use a table alias: `FROM PolicyCover pc` and `SUM(pc.Premium)`.

Comment: I've tried using the Cross Join method it does not work

Comment: "Does not work" says nothing. Are you saying that when you replace `FROM Agent, Policy, PolicyCover` with `FROM Agent CROSS JOIN Policy CROSS JOIN PolicyCover` you get a syntax error?

Comment: Yes precisely. We were told to use Microsoft Office Access by the way

Comment: When I use the Inner Join method I still get a blank database

Comment: Okay. MS Access is not a good DBMS and is far from standard compliant. It doesn't support `CROSS JOIN` and you are really forced to use the comma instead. However, cross joins are a very rare thing and you don't need them for the task given.

Comment: As to inner joins not working: So you have read and understood everything I've said? You fixed the joins, the where clause and the subquery in the select clause? Then show that query.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not as simple as this?

```
select (salary + commission) "sum of commission and salary"
from agent
where (salary + commission) < (select min(salary) from agent where function = 'Manager')
```

Comment: No  I'm not allowed to add the salary +commission as an attribute in the table